# Changing Days Results Row Into Weeks SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the current query

```
select (current_timestamp - dstat.updated_at) as days_since_activation
from trips
```

which returns

```
days_since_activation
  77 days, 9:41:23.764788
```

How would I turn this into weeks instead of days and a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT 
(EXTRACT(WEEK FROM current_timestamp) - EXTRACT(WEEK FROM updated_at)) 
AS weeks_since_activation
FROM trips
```

Or:

```
SELECT FLOOR(date_part('days',(current_timestamp - updated_at)) / 7) 
AS weeks_since_activation
FROM trips;
```

See [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3a435/1)